# Как отобразить блок с помощью option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

Есть вот такой код:

```
<select>
  <option id="umor">Юмор</option>
  <option id="music">Музыка</option>
  <option id="images">Картинки</option>
  <option id="video">Видео</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать, допустим, так, чтобы при выборе `<option id="music">Музыка</option>` появлялся только

```
<div class="music"></div>
```

Пробовал:

```
$("#music").click(function(){
    $(".music").show();
});
```

Не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для определения изменения выбора в селекте используется функция `change()`, [вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw3bphmv/) того, как можно сделать вашу логику.

HTML:

```
<select id="selectItem">
    <option id="umor">Юмор</option>
    <option id="music">Музыка</option>
    <option id="images">Картинки</option>
    <option id="video">Видео</option>
</select>
<div class="container">
    <div class="umor">Показываем юмор</div>
    <div class="music">Показываем музыку</div>
    <div class="images">Показываем картинки</div>
    <div class="video">Показываем видео</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.umor').show();

$("#selectItem").change(function(){
    $('.container').find('div').hide();
    var selected = $('#selectItem option:selected').attr('id');
    $('.' + selected).show();
});
```

Comment: Блок показывается, но при этом не скрывается.

Comment: Посмотрите пример, возможно, вам нужно сделать контейнер, как там, там же всё скрывается.